# Slang between languages

Tags: coloquialismos

How do you translate "I got you!" into Spanish (as in "I got you covered", or "I got your back" kind of way).

Comment: Welcome to Spanish Language Stack Exchange. Please provide more details about the intended usage and audience of the translation. Spanish has many variants; there might be a huge number of answers if you do not set boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

El verbo *get (got)* suele traducirse literalmente como *tener* o *conseguir*. Por supuesto que esto no es lo que estás buscando como respuesta: cuando forma parte de un *phrasal verb* (*get up*, *get off*, etc.) el mismo no parece aportar un significado en concreto. De esta forma, la primera afirmación mencionada parece resquebrajarse más que la ‘casta’.

Basándonos en la pregunta, el contexto que estás buscando es el de *ayudar a alguien cuando sea necesario*. A menos que estés literalmente en guerra con alguien, las frases ‘te cubro’ o ‘te cubro la espalda’ no van a funcionar, suenan muy militares.

En la Argentina lo que directamente decimos es **te hago la gamba**, o bien **te hago el aguante**. Ambas expresiones son informales pero no se restringen a ningún sector en específico. Usala sin miedo.

Comment: get es muy complicado y puede ser muchíssimas cosas: comprar, coger, llegar, recibir...no se traduce literalmente...I got you (to catch someone who is falling) puede aun ser: Te paro la caída, por ejemplo. Tambien, entendi lo que dijiste. Otro ejemplo.

Answer (score -3):

An online translator like [DeepL Translate](https://www.deepl.com/translator) suggests:

- I got you: te tengo
- I got you covered: te tengo cubierto
- I got your back: te cubro las espaldas

Comment: Looking for a translation that fits more the slang meaning of "I got you" versus the literal translation.

Comment: @Anna: What is the slang meaning of "I got you"?

Comment: @Fadrique As an example of a slang usage of "I got you", if I am out at a restaurant with a friend, I could indicate that I'll pay for their part of the bill by saying "I got you" when it arrives.  What Anna is asking for is what would the *equivalent* be in Spanish, not the literal translation.

Comment: I got you. =also, I'm stopping you from falling.